# Is it possible to have a factory method in an abstract class to force children classes

Tags: flutter, dart, oop, inheritance

I've created an abstract class named BaseModel and it has a toMap() method which return a map data. When I create a new class which inherits from BaseModel, the parent forces the child class to implement toMap method.
Now I want to create a factory method named fromMap which gets a Map and returns the instance of that class. I also want to do something to force children classes implement fromMap factory method.
How can I do that?

```
abstract class BaseModel {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap();
  
//   I want to have a factory method which should be implemented in children classes
//   factory BaseModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mapData);
}

class TestModel extends BaseModel {
  final int id;
  final String name;

  const TestModel({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
  
  TestModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mapData) {
    return TestModel(id: mapData['id'], name: mapData['name'])
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'name': name
    };
  }

}
```

I want to use it in my Pagination class:

```
class Pagination<T extends BaseModel> {
  final int count;
  final String? next;
  final String? previous;
  final List<T> result;

  Pagination({
    required this.count,
    required this.next,
    required this.previous,
    required this.result,
  });

  factory Pagination.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> mapData) {
    return Pagination(
      count: mapData['count'],
      next: mapData['next'],
      previous: mapData['previous'],
      result: mapData['result'].map<T>((e) => T.fromMap(e)).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

What can I do to be able to use fromMap method in result?

Comment: You cannot do what you want.  Dart does not consider constructors (`factory` or otherwise) and `static` methods to be part of the class's interface.  They are not inherited.   I strongly recommend using [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) or [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value) and avoid implementing your own serialization/deserialization code. Alternatively pass around a `fromMap`callback appropriate for that type.